# Is it possible to choose the app to open every-time if there are multiple supported app on the iOS universal link installed on device?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links, aasa

I have an Apple App Site Association file which contains multiple apps.

If a user has all the app, on the first time the iOS gives the option to select the app to open the link.

But on the second time iOS automatically select the first selection.

Is there any way to make sure that the user is giver the option to select the which app to open the link all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Branch generated AASA files have only 1 app association. It is typically a 1:1 co-relation.

The current issue as described will occur if a single AASA file denotes to multiple apps.

Requesting you to change the config here so as to map each app with its respective AASA file. This would a scenario when each of your app's link will open the respective app, as it is supposed to.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
But I want the users to get an option to select the app they prefer every time rather than implementing separate AASA file for each app.
Is there any way to implement this design?

Comment: Unfortunately the AASA file will prompt the user for a selection here on the first time to assign itself to an app. From the next time, the selected app will open.

Comment: Is there any way to override this design flow?